# Setting different cookies for different users under embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, session-cookies

We have a project which contains an embedded Tomcat. This project is run under different environments (development and qs). So we have 2 instances of our project running with different configuration files.
What happens is that if two (different or same) users authenticated by LDAP log on, the last one disconnects the first one because the cookie name (JSESSIONID) is the same.

tomcat1, user A connects, gets a Cookie called JESSIONSID
tomcat2, user B connects, gets a Cookie called JESSIONSID which overrides the old one

How can I change this?